# Cake PHP joining same model on two tables

Tags: cakephp, associations, models

I have a question regarding model association. Consider the following application: each month a new question is asked to the users. These have the ability to give a tip on this question and other users have the ability to react on this tip. My model-setup is like this:

```
Users hasMany Tips, Reactions

Tips belongsTo User

Tips hasMany Reactions

Reactions belongsTo User, Tip
```

Now I want to get all the tips on that question from all users. I do a simple find all on the tips-table which return me all tips joined with their user and reactions. The reactions however do not contain the user, which is very important, obviously.

Cake automatically converts my find all to two queries: one on the tips-table joining the user and one on the reactions table, but there is no join on the users-table, which is what i need.

So my question is: why is the users-table not joined with the reactions and how can i solve this?

Code:

User-model:

```
public $hasMany = array('Tip', 'Reaction');
```

Tip-model:

```
public $hasMany = array('Reaction' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'tip_id'
    ));

public $hasOne = array('User' => array(
        'fields' => array(
            'User.id, User.first_name, User.last_name'
        ),
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ));
```

Reaction-model:

```
public $belongsTo = array('Tip', 'ReactionUser' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'id'
    ));
```

Controller:

```
$tips = $this->Tip->find('all');
```

OUTPUT:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Tip' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'user_id' => '1',
            'question_id' => '1',
            'tip' => 'Testing da new datavbase',
            'votes' => '0',
            'approved' => '1',
            'pic' => '',
            'created' => '2012-05-18 09:22:56'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '1',
            'first_name' => 'Bart',
            'last_name' => 'De Bock'
        ),
        'Reaction' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'tip_id' => '1',
                'user_id' => '1',
                'reaction' => 'lorem ipsum',
                'votes' => '0',
                'approved' => '1',
                'pic' => '',
                'created' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'Tip' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'user_id' => '2',
            'question_id' => '1',
            'tip' => 'Test',
            'votes' => '0',
            'approved' => '1',
            'pic' => '',
            'created' => '2012-05-18 10:22:51'
        ),
        'User' => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'first_name' => 'Deborah',
            'last_name' => 'Rochtus'
        ),
        'Reaction' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '2',
                'tip_id' => '2',
                'user_id' => '3',
                'reaction' => 'Say whaat?',
                'votes' => '2',
                'approved' => '1',
                'pic' => '',
                'created' => '2012-05-18 10:33:32'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'tip_id' => '2',
                'user_id' => '4',
                'reaction' => 'Hmmm..',
                'votes' => '0',
                'approved' => '1',
                'pic' => '',
                'created' => '2012-05-18 10:33:44'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

As you can see, these reactions do not contain the associated user...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: show me your code ,, what have u tried??

Comment: please show me your full code of controller....  ur modal is looking fine..

Comment: print_r($tips);  what it is showing...

Comment: in modal basically we have to define like this:    var $belongsTo = array(
        'UserProduct' => array(
            'className' => 'UserProduct',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_product_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ));

Answer (score 0):

Use Containable:

In AppModel:

`public $uses = array('Containable');`

Change your find call to:

`$this->Tip->find('all', array('contain' => array('User', 'Reaction' => array('User'))));`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

`$tips = $this->Tip->find('all'
  array(
    'recursive'=>'2'
  )
);`

recursive value maybe 1, 2, 3, 4 etc as you need.